# Call a Variable inside HTML with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through radio button values and add them up for a quiz.  My question is how to call a variable for "name" inside this statement:

```
   answer = $("input[type='radio'][name='q1']:checked");
```

I need to increment q1 by 1 in my loop.  I thought I could use my variable q for this, just not sure how to stick it in there:

```
   for (var j=1; j < 11; j++) 
   {
     q="q"+j;
     answer = $("input[type='radio'][name='q1']:checked");
     answer = answer.val();
     answer = Number(answer);
     total = total + answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use concatination like :

```
answer = $("input[type='radio'][name='"+q+"']:checked");
```